# What is a well balanced party setup for Wizardry 8?

Tags: wizardry-8

It is a while since I played Wizardry 8 and I actually forgot a lot about the game.
So while trying to do a good party, I had a lot of problems at the start, especially with ranged enemies.

**How do you set up your party so it is well balanced against each close combat and ranged enemies?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, Wizardry 8. Such a lovely (and occasionally annoying) game. The question is a bit ambiguous since a well composed party is somewhat up toyou and what you like. But my most successful playthough I think I went with

- Fighter - Lizardman
- Lord - Dracon
- Samurai - Felpurr
- Gadgeteer - Hobbit
- Priest - Rawulf
- Mage - Faerie

Pretty standard with heavy fighters in the front and ranged in tha back. One thing you should note is that if you go with gadgeteer or bard you should go female. There is a necklace that regenerates stamina and it can only be worn by females. Also there are quite a few items that can be worn by only a certain race and class combo. Such as the Cane of Corpus which only a faerie ninja can wield.

In the end, it's really up to you. But you can't go wrong with the old standard RPG party - heavy fighters, ranged a healer and offensive casters.